# Cryptogen: command not found

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to add a new peer to a SOLO hyperledger setup. I used hyperledger composer. I updated the crypto-config.yaml file to make the count for peers to 2 and also other changes. But when I try to run this command under hlfv1/composer cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml, I get this error Cryptogen command not found. How to I fix that? I used the fabric-dev-servers scripts from the link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html to setup my development environment.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to install Hyperledger Fabric native binaries. The Composer playground does not use these for their sample.

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.2.0 1.2.0 0.4.10 -s -d
```

This will download the binaries for Hyperledger Fabric 1.2 and place them in a directory named `bin` in your current working directory. It will also create a `config` directory with the default config files for the Hyperledger Fabric sample applications. To download version 1.1 binaries.

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.1 1.1.0 0.4.7 -s -d
```